# Member function doesn't see the private member of the class

Tags: class, visual-c++

Member function (`reverseString()`) has to turn the string but when I create and try to initialize a new pointer in the member function (`char *temporary = stringo;`), it aparently doesn't see the member of the class (That's not the whole code though).

```
#include"Header.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

Stringfuncs::Stringfuncs(char *string)
{
this->stringo = string;
}

int Stringfuncs::lengthString()
{
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; stringo[i]; i++) { counter++; }

return counter;
}

char Stringfuncs::*reverseString()   //this function doesn't see the member of the class
{
char *temporary = stringo;  //identifier "stringo" isn't defined
}
```

Comment: `char Stringfuncs::*reverseString()` doesn't make sense and shouldn't compile; the star is in the wrong place. Show a [mcve]

Comment: `reverseString` is a function (at namespace scope) that returns a pointer-to-member of class `Stringfuncs` that is of type `char`. It is not a member function of class `Stringfuncs`. And that's the reason that it does not see the members.